# Problemas en este código de verificacion entre padre y alumno

Tags: php, mysql, sql, formularios

tengo un problema, y es que estoy haciendo la página web de un colegio, pero para hacer la relación entre padre e hijo se me ha ocurrido que cuando sea la primera vez que el padre inicie sesión le rediriga a una página distinta, hasta ahí todo bien, le redirige a este php:
**registrar_hijo1.php**

```
<main class="admin__main">
  <div class="dashboard__item">
    <div class="card">
      <form class="padre-hijo" action="registrar_hijo2.php" method="post">
      <?php echo "<h4>HOLA, $_SESSION[usuario]</h4>"; ?>
            <h4>Como es tu primera vez, que tal si nos das los datos de tu hijo</h4>      
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Nombre</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Nombre..." required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Correo electrónico</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email..." required>
            </div>
            <div class="der">
                <input type="Submit" value="Cambiar" name="entrar"  class="btn  btn--primary">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

y el problema para crear la relación esta en este php:
**registrar_hijo2.php**

```
        <?php
    session_start();

    // Comprobación de que se han enviado los datos por POST
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $nombre = $_POST["name"];
    $correo = $_POST["email"];

    // Comprobación de que los campos no están vacíos
    if (empty($nombre) || empty($correo)) {
        echo "<script language='javascript'>
            alert('¡¡¡Por favor, ingrese los datos requeridos!!!');
            window.location.replace('./registrar_hijo.php')
            </script>";
        exit();
    }

    $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "rootroot", "educados") or die("No se puede conectar con la base de datos");

    // Verificar si el hijo existe en la base de datos
    $query = "SELECT id_usuario, nombre FROM alumno WHERE nombre='$nombre' AND correo='$correo'";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);

    if ($resultado && mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
        $id_hijo = $row["id_usuario"];
        $hijo = $row["nombre"];

        // Actualizar la tabla de padres con el ID del hijo y nombre correspondiente
        $query2 = "UPDATE padre SET id_hijo='$id_hijo', hijo='$hijo' WHERE correo='$correo'";
        if(mysqli_query($conexion, $query2)){
        echo "<script language='javascript'>
            alert('¡¡¡Todo correcto, muchas gracias!!!');
            window.location.replace('./padreindex.php')
            </script>";
        } else {
        echo "<script language='javascript'>
            alert('¡¡¡Error en la actualización de datos, por favor, inténtelo de nuevo!!!');
            window.location.replace('./registrar_hijo.php')
            </script>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<script language='javascript'>
            alert('¡¡¡Los datos ingresados no corresponden a un hijo!!!');
            window.location.replace('./registrar_hijo.php')
            </script>";
    }

    mysqli_close($conexion);
    } else {
    echo "<script language='javascript'>
            alert('¡¡¡Se ha producido un error en la petición, por favor, inténtelo de nuevo!!!');
            window.location.replace('./registrar_hijo.php')
            </script>";
    }
    ?>
```

tengo tres tablas en my .sql y ningún trigger para que no de ningún error:

```
        CREATE TABLE alumno(
        id_usuario INT(4) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
        nombre VARCHAR(50),
        correo VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        contraseña VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
        id_curso INT(4),
        FOREIGN KEY (id_curso) REFERENCES curso(id_curso)
    );

    CREATE TABLE padre (
        id_usuario INT(4) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
        usuario VARCHAR(50),
        correo VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        contraseña VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
        id_hijo INT(4),
        hijo VARCHAR(50),
        primer_login BOOLEAN DEFAULT true,
        FOREIGN KEY (id_hijo) REFERENCES alumno(id_usuario)
    );

    CREATE TABLE padre_hijo(
        id_relación INT(4) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
        id_padre INT(4),
        id_usuario INT(4),
        FOREIGN KEY (id_padre) REFERENCES padre(id_usuario),
        FOREIGN KEY (id_usuario) REFERENCES alumno(id_usuario)
    );
```

He comprobado todo tipo de cosas y he probado si un insert directamente en la terminal funciona y si, sinceramente creo que el problema está en registrar_hijo2.php.

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Cuando decìs que el problema está al crear la relacion, ¿a que error te referís? no comprendo esa parte, que error te lanza por ejemplo. Por otra parte, creo que te ahorrarías la tabla padre_hijo si a la table alumno, le colocás el id_usuario de la tabla padre. Pero primero vayamos con el error.

Comment: Me parece estas medio enredado en la lógica del asunto...con 2 tablas y relacionadas por algún campo en común te bastaría para comenzar.  Con lo que estás haciendo, que esperas del script y que error te dá?

Comment: A relación me refiero a la relación que existe entre padre y alumno, que es la tercera tabla y no la puedo quitar porque la relación entre padre y alumno es de "N, M", es decir, varios padres pueden tener varios hijos, y viceversa. En este php lo que yo hago es actualizar padre donde tengo "id_hijo INT(4), hijo VARCHAR(50)", y así tener los datos del hijo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realmente tienes un poco de lío en todo: en la lógica que estás siguiendo, en el diseño de las tablas, en la nomenclatura que usas, etc.

Me voy a centrar en el diseño de las tablas, porque mientras no resuelvas el lío que tienes ahí, no resolverás nada, dando palos de ciego en el código, o queriendo resolver en PHP algo que debiste resolver en la base de datos.

Tener una tabla `padre_hijo` podría ser el camino correcto para este tipo de situaciones si existiera una relación muchos a muchos entre padre e hijo, pero no es el caso porque un hijo sólo puede tener un padre.

Entonces el asunto de la relación quedaría resuelto introduciendo una columna `id_padre` en la tabla `alumno`.

Dicho eso, no se entiende qué es la columna `id_relación` (por cierto evita acentos y `ñ` en nombres de tablas y columnas) ni a qué hace referencia `id_usuario` en la tabla `padre_hijo`.

Esta afirmación en tu pregunta es desconcertante:

> tengo tres tablas en my .sql y **ningún trigger para que no de ningún
> error**...

¿Por qué un `TRIGGER` debería dar error? ¿Por qué hay que evitar los `TRIGGER`, cuando podrían ser la forma idónea de controlar las cosas y de mantener la integridad de los datos? Aquí no se aprecia su utilidad, porque no hace falta una tabla asociativa, debido a lo ya dicho: un hijo no puede tener más que un padre.

Luego, en la tabla `padre` tienes otro lío. ¿Por qué tienes en ella una columna `id_hijo` y otra columna `hijo` ¿? La relación entre `padre` e `hijo` debes gestionarla desde la tabla hijo, poniendo allí el id del padre. Con tu diseño actual, en la tabla `padre`, por cada hijo del mismo tendrías que tener una fila con los datos del padre duplicados.

Vamos a ver un diseño aplicando lo dicho. Luego, resuelve lo que tengas que resolver a nivel de PHP.

```
CREATE TABLE `curso`
(
  `id_curso` INT(4) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `curso` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `padre` 
(
  `id_padre` INT(4) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `usuario` VARCHAR(50),
  `correo` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  `password` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `primer_login` BOOLEAN DEFAULT true
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `alumno`(
  `id_alumno` INT(4) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_padre` INT(4) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(50),
  `correo` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  `password` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `id_curso` INT(4),
  FOREIGN KEY (`id_padre`) REFERENCES `padre`(`id_padre`) 
      ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,  
  FOREIGN KEY (`id_curso`) REFERENCES `curso`(`id_curso`)
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

```
INSERT INTO `curso` (`id_curso`,`curso`) VALUES (1,'Curso1');
INSERT INTO `curso` (`id_curso`,`curso`) VALUES (2,'Curso2');

INSERT INTO `padre` (`id_padre`,`usuario`,`correo`,`password`,`primer_login`) VALUES (1,'usuario1','u1@example.com','123',true);
INSERT INTO `padre` (`id_padre`,`usuario`,`correo`,`password`,`primer_login`) VALUES (2,'usuario2','u2@example.com','456',true);
INSERT INTO `padre` (`id_padre`,`usuario`,`correo`,`password`,`primer_login`) VALUES (3,'usuario1','u3@example.com','789',true);

INSERT INTO `alumno` (`id_alumno`,`id_padre`,`nombre`,`correo`,`password`,`id_curso`) VALUES (1,1,'Alumno1DePadre1','a1p1@example.com','A1',1);
INSERT INTO `alumno` (`id_alumno`,`id_padre`,`nombre`,`correo`,`password`,`id_curso`) VALUES (2,1,'Alumno2DePadre1','a2p1@example.com','A2',2);
INSERT INTO `alumno` (`id_alumno`,`id_padre`,`nombre`,`correo`,`password`,`id_curso`) VALUES (3,2,'Alumno1DePadre2','a1p2@example.com','A3',2);
INSERT INTO `alumno` (`id_alumno`,`id_padre`,`nombre`,`correo`,`password`,`id_curso`) VALUES (4,2,'Alumno2DePadre2','a2p2@example.com','A4',2);
INSERT INTO `alumno` (`id_alumno`,`id_padre`,`nombre`,`correo`,`password`,`id_curso`) VALUES (5,3,'Alumno1DePadre3','a1p3@example.com','A5',1);
```

```
-- Datos en la tabla curso
SELECT * FROM `curso`;
```

| id_curso | curso |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Curso1 |
| 2 | Curso2 |

```
-- Datos en la tabla padre
SELECT * FROM `padre`;
```

| id_padre | usuario | correo | password | primer_login |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | usuario1 | u1@example.com | 123 | 1 |
| 2 | usuario2 | u2@example.com | 456 | 1 |
| 3 | usuario1 | u3@example.com | 789 | 1 |

```
-- Datos en la tabla alumno
SELECT * FROM `alumno`;
```

| id_alumno | id_padre | nombre | correo | password | id_curso |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Alumno1DePadre1 | a1p1@example.com | A1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | Alumno2DePadre1 | a2p1@example.com | A2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | Alumno1DePadre2 | a1p2@example.com | A3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 | Alumno2DePadre2 | a2p2@example.com | A4 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 | Alumno1DePadre3 | a1p3@example.com | A5 | 1 |

```
-- Los hijos de un padre
SELECT 
    `a`.`id_alumno`,
    `a`.`nombre`,
    `p`.`usuario` AS `padre`,
    `c`.`curso`
FROM `alumno` AS `a`
    INNER JOIN `padre` AS `p` ON `a`.`id_padre`=`p`.`id_padre`
    INNER JOIN `curso` AS `c` ON `a`.`id_curso`=`c`.`id_curso`
WHERE `p`.`id_padre`=1;
```

| id_alumno | nombre | padre | curso |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alumno1DePadre1 | usuario1 | Curso1 |
| 2 | Alumno2DePadre1 | usuario1 | Curso2 |

```
/*
    Prueba de integridad referencial en el caso de DELETE
    Borraremos al padre 1 y se borrarán los hijos
    en la tabla `alumno` como en la tabla `padre_hijo`
*/
DELETE FROM `padre` WHERE `id_padre`=1;
```

```
/*
    Contenido de alumno después del DELETE
    al borrarse el padre 1 se borran todos sus hijos
*/
SELECT * FROM `alumno`;
```

| id_alumno | id_padre | nombre | correo | password | id_curso |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 | Alumno1DePadre2 | a1p2@example.com | A3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 | Alumno2DePadre2 | a2p2@example.com | A4 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 | Alumno1DePadre3 | a1p3@example.com | A5 | 1 |

```
/*
    Prueba de integridad referencial en el caso de UPDATE
    Aunque esto es poco probable, cambiamos el id del padre 3
    y vemos como cambia en la tabla `alumno`
*/
UPDATE `padre` SET `id_padre`=4 WHERE `id_padre`=3;
```

> ```
> Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
-- Contenido de alumno después del UPDATE
SELECT * FROM `alumno`;
```

| id_alumno | id_padre | nombre | correo | password | id_curso |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 | Alumno1DePadre2 | a1p2@example.com | A3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 | Alumno2DePadre2 | a2p2@example.com | A4 | 2 |
| 5 | 4 | Alumno1DePadre3 | a1p3@example.com | A5 | 1 |

```
-- Contenido de alumno después del UPDATE
SELECT * FROM `padre`;
```

| id_padre | usuario | correo | password | primer_login |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | usuario2 | u2@example.com | 456 | 1 |
| 4 | usuario1 | u3@example.com | 789 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lBv0dbwX)

Comment: Perdón, se me olvidó comentar que la solución era más fácil de lo que era, en el inicio de sesión, no tenía `$_SESSION['correo'] = $correo;`, entonces por ello, no me cambiaba en la tabla pero tampoco saltaba error, tengo la respuesta pero no me deja publicarla.

Comment: @NovatoEnEsto nada impide que publiques una respuesta a tu propio pregunta. Pero independientemente del problema en el código PHP había un grave problema en el diseño de las tablas.